# Dynamically change icon in jQuery Mobile listview

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, icons

When I dynamically change the icon, it does not reflect the change on the page, even though in the markup it was changed.

Example:

```
      <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
        <li data-icon="check"><a href="#">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
        <li data-icon="check"><a href="#">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
        <li data-icon="check"><a href="#">Avery Johnson</a></li>
        <li data-icon="check"><a href="#">Bob Cabot</a></li>
        <li data-icon="check"><a href="#">Caleb Booth</a></li>
        <li data-icon="check"><a href="#">Christopher Adams</a></li>
        <li data-icon="check"><a href="#">Culver James</a></li>
    </ul>

$("li").tap(function() {
    //Alert the old icon
    alert($(this).jqmData("icon"));

    //Toggle
    $(this).jqmData("icon") == "false" ? $(this).jqmData("icon", "check") :             $(this).jqmData("icon", "false");

    //Alert the new icon
    alert($(this).jqmData("icon"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mc97V/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qgE6L/

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $("li").tap(function() {
        $(this).buttonMarkup({ icon: "edit" });
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this mostly works. However, toggling between check/false, instead of false, it shows a blurry +. Toggling between any two others shows the icons correctly

Comment: That's because icon "false" don't exist. Take a look at this icon list: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html. You can add your own custom icons, but that is another question. Or do you want to remove icon with false?

Comment: I want to remove the icon with false, yeah

Comment: NVM, got it. I used .buttonMarkup({ icon: "" }). Thanks for your help